# Remove duplicates in foreach loop from custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

It shows this result in the foreach loop and it should remove any duplicates

```
spain
philippines
spain
```

I tried using array_unique() but its not working for me

This is the code I'm using and working fine, its just that it has duplicates

```
<?php 
if (is_tax() || is_category() || is_tag() ){
    $qobj = get_queried_object();

    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $qobj->taxonomy,
          'field' => 'slug', 
          'terms' => $qobj->slug
        )
      )
    );

    $random_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($random_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($random_query->have_posts()) {
          $random_query->the_post();
            $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'country', array("all"));
            foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
                echo '<a href="'.dirname(get_the_permalink()).'">';
                echo $term_single->slug;
                echo '</a><br>';
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
} 
?>
```

added this for debugging - var_dump($term_list); and this is the result

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Term)[1464]
      public 'term_id' => int 2
      public 'name' => string 'Spain' (length=5)
      public 'slug' => string 'spain' (length=5)
      public 'term_group' => int 0
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 2
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'country' (length=7)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => int 0
      public 'count' => int 2
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Term)[1473]
      public 'term_id' => int 5
      public 'name' => string 'Philippines' (length=11)
      public 'slug' => string 'philippines' (length=11)
      public 'term_group' => int 0
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 5
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'country' (length=7)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => int 0
      public 'count' => int 2
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Term)[1475]
      public 'term_id' => int 2
      public 'name' => string 'Spain' (length=5)
      public 'slug' => string 'spain' (length=5)
      public 'term_group' => int 0
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 2
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'country' (length=7)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => int 0
      public 'count' => int 2
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

All I need is to remove the duplicates and I am set, I not not very familiar with this and its very complicated, I'm trying to figure this out since yesterday, anybody please help me get it working or just in the right track, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep a list of those already displayed, then before displaying a new one check if it in that list (using `in_array()`).  Once displayed, add this into the already displayed list to stop it appearing again...

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'country', array("all"));
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
    if ( !in_array( $term_single->slug, $alreadyDisplayed) ) {
        echo '<a href="'.dirname(get_the_permalink()).'">';
        echo $term_single->slug;
        echo '</a><br>';
        $alreadyDisplayed[] =  $term_single->slug;
    }
}
```

You will need to have...

```
$alreadyDisplayed = [];
```

before the line

```
while ($random_query->have_posts()) {
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but its not working, can still see duplicates

Comment: Can you try moving the `$alreadyDisplayed = [];`  before the line `while ($random_query->have_posts()) {
`